# Replacing \\ with \ in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I have a requirement where I want to replace `"\\"` with `"\"` however it does not seem to work.

```
var st = "satya\\"
st = st.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "\", options: 
NSString.CompareOptions.literal,
range: nil)
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly are you trying to replace. Can you specify your desired result after replacing?

Comment: both the target string and occurring string look same to me. or is it?

Comment: `\ ` is an escape character. In computing and telecommunication, an escape character is a character which invokes an alternative interpretation on subsequent characters in a character sequence. If you define a string like you did: `var st = "satya\\ ";` the value of the string will be `satya\ `. If that is the desired string you don't need to replace anything.

Comment: this is my playground example and its working without doing anything.   import UIKit

var str = "satya\\"

print(str)

Comment: Hi Saty, a quick reminder, related to the edits I sometimes make to your questions: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: Also, I notice that the first version of this question featured unformatted code, and this was fixed by a volunteer editor. Since you're a ~1K user, readers will generally expect that you know how to use the formatting tools. Please do use them, and refer to the preview window prior to submitting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should **escape the backslashes** if you want to replace two backslashes with one.

```
st.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\\", with: "\\", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

**However,** as [@VTodorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3311754/vtodorov) mentioned, `"satya\\"` is actually stored as `satya\`, since you already escaped a backlash in it. If you want to store a string with two backslashes, you should write it as `"satya\\\\"`.